Doesn't the running a presidential campaign distract an incumbent POTUS from the job?
It seems to me that every US president who spends the last year of his presidency campaigning to be re-elected must have much less time to do the current job.
Has the extent to which it is true ever been evaluated? Has any prominent politician ever expressed concerns that the main job is not being done properly if the president is occupied with being re-elected?

The same can be said about every political office and for some of them with short terms they have to worry about getting reelected the entire time they are in office.

@JoeW Okay, you can answer about any elected US political office if you can. Not fixated on POTUS. It's just that if it ever was evaluated/spoken about, it'll likely be about POTUS before any other office.

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for here, every elected official is distracted by the next election even if they are not running again. It tends to be a rare situation where a politician doesn't care about who gets elected next and doesn't want the successor to be someone from their own party. No matter how you look at it this isn't a unique situation for the president and some have it even worse such as members of the house of representatives who have a large focus on fundraising that impacts what roles they get the entire time they are in office.

I think case is similar also for the presidents in their second term, they are campaigning with/for their successor candidate. I think it is clearly a disadvantage for the USA. A lot of things can not be done this year, like sending the next package in Ukraine. Careful planning can handle it, probably Biden has the team running the business until he is flying USA-wide, but it is still not a real president.

@GraySheep There has been issues with Ukraine funding since the start of the conflict which was long before election season started up.

I've heard numerous Congress members say in interviews that it's annoying that they spend a great deal of their time calling campaign donors rather than legislating.

Arguably everything that's not direct decision making is pure distraction. Handing out medals is a distraction. Meeting sports people for a photo-op is a distraction. Giving interviews is a distraction. In an ideal world the President would do absolutely nothing other than managing the country and delegate everything else to his subordinates.

You ask:

Has any prominent politician ever expressed concerns that the main job is not being done properly if the president is occupied with being re-elected?

And you clarify:

you can answer about any elected US political office if you can. Not fixated on POTUS.

The answer is yes. In Senator McCain suspended his presidential campaign to focus on the financial crisis and asked then Senator Obama to do the same:

"I cannot carry on a campaign as though this dangerous situation had not occurred, or as though a solution were at hand, which it clearly is not," he says. "As of this morning I suspended my political campaign. With so much on the line, for America and the world, the debate that matters most right now is taking place in the United States Capitol."


That looks a little bit campaign-ish for me :-)

I am not sure this is a great example.  Neither McCain, nor Obama, were incumbent POTUS at the time, so they weren't neglecting POTUS duties.  Their constituents in their home states might have some grounds for concern, but not the general US population.  In fact, strictly speaking, McCain constituents might have greater cause for concern for him looking after a national level issue (the financial crisis), rather than homeground considerations - whatever Arizona's interests were at that time.

@GraySheep Perhaps you might want to enlighten us in which way McCain did not in fact act as he stated?  As opposed to just making an apparently popular quip, in line with the public's general cynicism and  contempt for politicians.

@Jen My point is McCain was not an incumbent in the position he was campaigning for.  That that position was POTUS is not that relevant to my remark.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Okay, I think that's clear in my answer: I call him a Senator, and talk about his presidential campaign. If this doesn't address what the question author had in mind, I trust they'll tell me.

In a democracy, getting elected is part of the job!
By analogy you could ask if preparing for the test distracts students from learning. Perhaps there is something to be said for that point of view, but being a student means not only studying new skills and learning, but also developing the ability to present and apply those skills in a formal assessment.
For a politician, in a democracy, the job is not just "running the country", but also demonstrating to the electorate that they have run the country effectively and competently enough to justify remaining in power.  The alternative: a leader who governs without the "distraction" of having to justify themselves to the electorate is a far worse option! (See Russia 1917, Germany 1933 and any other number of examples)

Not buying this at all. If getting elected was part of the job, how come newbie candidates would be allowed to do job they haven't yet been elected for? Also, no need to conflate not being distracted with being a dictator.

"ow come newbie candidates would be allowed to do job"  Because they get elected... Really that is the only requirement

"but also demonstrating to the electorate that they have run the country effectively and competently enough to justify remaining in power." Shouldn’t this be achieved by running the country effectively and competently instead of by campaigning?

AFAIK the last Russian czar did do a lot of campaigning as well via public appearances, big donations, etc, even if he wasn't up for election.

@MisterMiyagi The problem is if you are running the country effectively and competently there are a lot of things that the people will never hear of. There is a reason why you hear many political commentators state that politicians needs to the people what they did and how it helped them.

@MisterMiyagi My analogy works here too.  A lot of time in history class should be spent on learning history.  But you also need to learn how to write a good essay.  If you can't write a good essay in history class, it doesn't matter how much history you've learned.  If you can't get people to vote for you it doesn't matter how good your management of the country is.  This is the (small) price paid for democracy.  The alternative is ... worse.

First, yes, there is a slowdown during electoral cycles.  It is common to see news coverage with statements like: "if this bill doesn't pass now, it is unlikely to happen soon due to the coming elections".
Second, campaigning is part of the job, convincing your electorate you are worthy.
Third, let's look at what a typical politician might be doing with their time:

campaigning - the subject of this question
reacting - taking care of sudden events:  a hurricane, a war somewhere,  etc...
managing - i.e. looking after the day-to-day running of the government.  In most democracies, this will be less the leader's job than their staff and cabinet's, as well as the job of civil servant heads of departments and ministries.  So it doesn't seem all that relevant to this question.
defining laws, goals and policy - long term work to achieve policy goals, pass laws, budgets, dealing with controversial long-term issues etc...

Clearly, campaigning will absorb considerable time.  Reacting to current events will still need to happen and the electorate can be expected to punish incumbents who shirk that - "X did not visit city Y after its hurricane because he was at a rally in Z" is a look most politicians are keen to avoid because that is how neglectful incumbents will be punished - on election day.  On the other hand, successful crisis management is the bread and butter of an incumbent, giving ample opportunities for photo ops.
In fact, it is not uncommon for the (opposition) press in a country to sourly remark how an incumbent is busy doing all sorts of (non-campaigning) things to keep themselves in the media spotlight.  Kinda the opposite of the claim this question is based on.
The last type of work, slow, deliberate, efforts on things like laws or reforms, especially controversial ones, like spending cuts, do take a backseat * during electoral times and that's where there is some justification to this question.  However, most countries do not spend nearly an entire year on elections, so this effect is less pronounced outside the US. **
But, what's the alternative?  That politicians can only ever serve one term, lest they be distracted?  Even ones that do a really good job?
Finally, look at it from the point of view of the incumbent's party and supporters:  if they are satisfied with the job he's doing, would you not expect them to want the incumbent to invest enough effort to keep his job, rather than handing it over to the opposition?
* Not everything policy-related slows down.  Depending on the budgeting framework as well customs (and tolerance for "gaming") in any given country, you may very well see the government announce new spending initiatives for goody-goody causes (new shelter funding for puppies!) as well as (if the laws allow it) tax cuts.  Canadian governments rarely miss the boat on announcing some new spending initiative on something like health or child care during electoral cycles.
** - I tried to answer this in a deliberately non US-centric fashion, as I believe most rebuttals to these concerns are not US-specific.  Nor is this consideration specific to positions of national leadership like POTUS:  constituents at any level would have grounds to be concerned if their elected officials indeed neglected their duties in favor of campaigning.

Actually there are some one-term provisions in some countries, for some posts -- typically executive, so it's not terribly outlandish. Even the two-term US limit is a derivative of that. One of the concurrent proposals as the time was a six-year one-term limit.

Yeah, arguably a two-term limit is a balancing act between offering an incentive for a good first-term job and other considerations. OTOH some would argue that [ceteris paribus, i.e. not forced by overwhelming circumstance] some presidents avoid doing anything controversial or consequential in their first term as a result of this.

@timetakesitstoll How would one-term limits apply to this question, which is about re-election?  And, assuming you don't have them, then I stand by my statement that it doesn't make sense to throttle an incumbent's campaign overmuch.
